# Is there any formula that gives the number of permutations of a set including duplicate entries for the generated tuples?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a set `S = {a, b, c}` and I want all its permutations of 3 elements including tuples such as `(a, a, a), (a, b, b)`. Is there some formula that calculates the number of generated tuples? Thanks!

Comment: Well, there are $3$ choice for each of $3$ elements, so it's $3^3=27$.

Comment: Hrm, this is not what "permutations" is usually taken to mean.  The set of all ordered $k$-tuples of elements of a set $S$ has cardinality $|S|^k$, where $|S|$ is the cardinality of $S$. But are you asking for something more specific than the set of *all* ordered three-tuples?

Comment: Thank you to both of you! Yes that was what I was looking for, but for some reason I was thinking it was something more complicated haha. |S|^k is a good formula to keep in mind. Thank you!